# Does the suppressor (silencer) attachment do anything for you in hardcore matches?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Does the suppressor (silencer) attachment do anything for you in hardcore matches? I understand that it lessens the flash and sound of the gun, but compared to core games it seems a bit less useful.

For a while I *thought* I noticed that when you were killed by a gun with a silencer, it didn't tell you what direction the shot came from with the death camera (the camera immediately after you die; I'm not talking about the kill camera, since there's no kill camera in hardcore).

Answer (score 3):

I think its important to note that in hardcore players function almost solely on sound (due to the lack of HUD).  This is why headphones and ninja are significantly more popular for hardcore matches! With that being said and the consideration of different players ability with different attachments I would make the claim that a suppressor is one of the MOST important attachments in hardcore strictly due to the quieter gunshot noise.

The muffled sound of a silencer and the lack of muzzle flash is significantly harder for players to locate then that of an un-silenced weapon, while the damage reduction caused by wearing a silencer is negligible.  This gives you the same benefit you would receive in a non-hardcore game (not showing up on the HUD is the same as no noise in hardcore + the lack of muzzle flash) without the only draw back of the suppressor (lowered damage).

With that being said, I'm not sure if there is no 'pre-death' arrow caused by a suppressor.  Even if that is the case, that is such a small benefit that I wouldn't even include it in the list of silencer benefits.  The strength of the suppressor is the stealth.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Silencer is a lot more useful in HC. The main difference of HC from SC is that you die faster under fire, and the only good way to not die is to not get shot in the first place. Silencer definitely makes that easier (assuming you are not just sprinting around with SMG).

edit: To clarify. I don't think there is any functional difference. Its more of a value difference for not becoming instant target after firing a shot.

Answer (score 1):

A hardcore friend of mine has told me it doesn't show the direction when you're hit.

Are you talking the direction you look to see your body fall?

Comment: Yeah. Right after you die the camera snaps to the direction of the person who shot you, but I *think* if they have a silencer it doesn't do that. I'm not sure about the directional hit indicator.